# Bigger keyboard keys on iPhone 6 with iOS 8

Tags: iphone, keyboard, ios

I want a default keyboard with bigger keys. That's it.

No Swype, no SwiftKey, nothing fancy, no other customizations—I just want… bigger… keys. I have thick fingers and I dont want to use auto correct or prediction.

I know it's possible, because one of the apps I use (CamScanner Pro) has a bigger keyboard (taller) which types significantly better. I am desperate to get that keyboard by default everywhere, or any other third party option or fix that will make my keyboard keys bigger.

How do I achieve this?

Minuum and Thick Buttons rely on auto predict and dynamically enlarge keys… way too fancy for me: simple, default bigger keyboard, bigger keys. I am happy to sacrifice screen area for bigger keyboard.

[edit - now many months later, I still experience this problem. Over time I have used several apps that offer a keyboard with bigger keys within the app. I don't know how these apps can offer such a keyboard while it is unavailable anywhere else...]

Comment: There are some (unfortunately commercial) third party apps allowing you to enlarge the keyboard, for instance Minuum or Thick Buttons. As far as native support for this is concerned, I'm afraid the size of the keyboard is set by each app itself.

Comment: not what i'm looking for as both of these rely on auto predict to enlarge specific keys... i just want bigger keys :). Not dynamically, no auto predict... simple keyboard with bigger keys than the default keyboard.

Comment: The keyboard is landscape mode is much larger, would that work for you?

Comment: it isn't, it just has more buttons so it's larger, but the letter buttons are the same size.

Comment: You could [start a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) if you want to get people's attention.

Comment: Did you tried https://fleksy.com/ios8/ ? It seems to have bigger keys than the others...

Comment: Send [feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) to Apple.

Comment: Sent feedback to apple as suggested. Although I'm not really expecting a reply.

Answer (score 3):

Set your view to zoomed, and change your text size to whatever size you want.  This will allow your keyboard to be bigger and the font to stay the same size.  It does change the size of your icons.

Comment: bigger icons is something that I don't want :) I'm surprised that it turns out to be so difficult to just get a keyboard with bigger keys without compromise...

Answer (score 1):

Just do following steps
it’s in Settings: General: Accessibility: Keyboard
And then turn off Show Lowercase Keys

Comment: Does this make the keyboard larger?